# How to avoid change in position and size of UI element with the change of resolution in android?

Tags: android, xml, user-interface, resolution

I am developing my 1st android app and using xamarin. Everything else works fine but When I switch between different devices due to the change in resolution the position and size of my UI elements changes.Below is the Main.xml code i am using.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="@drawable/avsar_ui"
        android:weightSum="100"
        android:minWidth="200px"
        android:minHeight="200px"
        android:id="@+id/linearLayout1">
        <EditText
            android:text="name"
            android:textColor="?android:attr/searchWidgetCorpusItemBackground"
            android:inputType="textPersonName"
            android:layout_marginTop="225.0dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="25.0dp"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:background="@drawable/rounded_corner"
            android:layout_marginLeft="50.0dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="50.0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/PersonName" />
        <EditText
            android:text="Contact Number"
            android:textColor="?android:attr/searchWidgetCorpusItemBackground"
            android:inputType="numberSigned"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="@drawable/rounded_corner"
            android:layout_marginLeft="50.0dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="10.0dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="50.0dp"
            android:id="@+id/ContactNumber" />
        <EditText
            android:text="Address"
            android:textColor="?android:attr/searchWidgetCorpusItemBackground"
            android:inputType="textPostalAddress"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:background="@drawable/rounded_corner"
            android:layout_marginLeft="50.0dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="50.0dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="10.0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/Address" />
        <Spinner
            android:layout_width="125.0dp"
            android:background="@drawable/dropbox_bg"
            android:layout_marginLeft="50.0dp"
            android:layout_height="40.0dp"
            android:id="@+id/Quantity" />
        <Button
           android:background="@drawable/order_button"
           android:layout_marginBottom="60dp"
           android:layout_marginTop="100dp"
           android:layout_marginLeft="115.0dp"
           android:layout_marginRight="115.0dp"
           android:layout_width="150.0dp"
           android:layout_height="50.0dp"
           android:id="@+id/OrderButton" />
    </LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

Firstly -  avoid using `px`, if you want scalable layouts use `dp`.
Secondly - you're probably testing your layout on different screen sizes. 
There are 4 screen sizes in Android:

- **xlarge** screens are at least 960dp x 720dp
- **large** screens are at least 640dp x 480dp
- **normal** screens are at least 470dp x 320dp
- **small** screens are at least 426dp x 320dp

[image]

So while your layout will look the same on different **normal** devices, it will be smaller on **large** and **xlarge** devices since their screens have more dps. You might want to declare separate layouts for each screen size.

For more information consult the [Android Developers](http://developer.android.com/intl/pt-br/guide/practices/screens_support.html) documentation.

Comment: changed px to dp dint help